# How to integrate Spark, Livy and Nifi to execute spark code from jar

Tags: apache-spark, apache-nifi, livy

Is there a way, we can execute Spark code(package in jar) from Nifi, using Livy?

I can see in Nifi that using `ExecuteSparkInteractive`, we can submit custom code which can be run in spark cluster using livy. but what i want is , pass name of the jar file , main class in Nifi that connects Spark via Livy.

I see below article on this, but seems option like `Session JARs` is not available in plain Nifi installation.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Apache-Livy-Apache-NiFi-Apache-Spark-Executing-Scala-Classes/ta-p/247985

Comment: Well via the rest API it should certainly be possible

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Could you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Well NiFi can execute arbitrary code via bash/python scripts and I believe has also a processor to perform REST calls. You would need to 1) via HDFS web need to make sure to upload the JAR to a location accessible to Livy 2) use the REST API of Livi to start the job.

Comment: But apparently: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-livy-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.controller.livy.LivySessionController/ is also available in a more natively integrated format. Have you tried that one already?

Comment: Yes,  I saw that with respect to Nifi. We have to embed spark code within Nifi, which is not the case in my situation.

Comment: The link to the nifi controller service would contain a JAR parameter. But what do you mean with integrated? I thought that the controller service is natively integrated into NiFi - what would you want to have instead/more?